# Not getting elements in event listener of JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

I have created two HTML pages. But I am not getting element of second HTML page in JavaScript event listener.

My goal : Whenever anybody click on any product its picture, title and description replace with the image, title and description of single product page.
[first HTML page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNHxf.png)
[second HTML page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0USp4.png)

```js
product.forEach(function (products) {
  products.addEventListener("click", function (curr) {
    location.href = "http://127.0.0.1:5500/single.html";

    // element of first html page
    let productImg = curr.currentTarget.firstElementChild.firstElementChild;
    // element of second html page
    let img = document.querySelector(".sp-img");
  });
});
```

Comment: Your snippet is incomplete; what is `product`?

Comment: You are not going to be able to load a new page and run JavaScript after you do that. When you set the location, the page navigates away, code after that is gone.

Comment: **location.href** redirects the user stopping anything under it from happening

Comment: You cannot access any element "on the second page" from the first page's javascript.  Maybe you mis-spoke and meant popup window.  In that case -- it might not be loaded yet.